# Android JSON Exception - JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json, android-layout

I'm trying to read a json url

My Code:

```
// Creating JSON Parser instance
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

// getting JSON string from URL
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
```

If I execute my Code i'm not able to get String from URL

Here is my LogCat Error:

```
06-04 17:13:45.162: E/JSON Parser(15988): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value ["<a href='http:\/\/freshersadda.com\/jsonFeed\/faJsonFeedDetails.php?jid=12036'>SPICE JET Recruits Freshers Data Entry Operator in Gurgaon<\/a><br><br><br>","<a href='http:\/\/freshersadda.com\/jsonFeed\/faJsonFeedDetails.php?jid=12035'>TOSHIBA Freshers off Campus Drive Trainee Engineers in Bangalore <\/a><br><br><br>","<a href='http:\/\/freshersadda.com\/jsonFeed\/faJsonFeedDetails.php?jid=12034'>EMC Corporation Recruits Fresher Jobs Technical Support Engineers in bangalore<\/a><br><br><br>","<a href='http:\/\/freshersadda.com\/jsonFeed\/faJsonFeedDetails.php?jid=12033'>AON Hewitt Freshers Walk in Drive 4th to 8th June in Chennai<\/a><br><br><br>","<a href='http:\/\/freshersadda.com\/jsonFeed\/faJsonFeedDetails.php?jid=12032'>APPLIED MATERIALS Recruits Fresher Jobs Software Engineer on June in Bangalore<\/a><br><br><br>","<a href='http:\/\/freshersadda.com\/jsonFeed\/faJsonFeedDetails.php?jid=12031'>US TECH Solutions Recruits Off-Campus Drive: Trainee on 14th June in Panipat<\/a><br><br><br>","<a href='http:\/\/freshersadda.com\/jsonFeed\/faJsonFeedDetails.php?jid=12030'>SURPRISE SOLUTIONS Fresher Walk-in Software Engineer on 5th to 15th June in Chennai <\/a><br><br><br>","<a href='http:\/\/freshersadda.com\/jsonFeed\/faJsonFeedDetails.php?jid=12029'>MPHASIS Freshers Walk-in: Associate\/Senior Associate on 4th & 5th June in Bangalore<\/a><br><br><br>","<a href='http:\/\/freshersadda.com\/jsonFeed\/faJsonFeedDetails.php?jid=12028'>ARROWSOFTWARE Technologies Recruits MBA Jobs: HR Last Date: 10th June in Hyderabad<\/a><br><br><br>","<a href='http:\/\/freshersadda.com\/jsonFeed\/faJsonFeedDetails.php?jid=12027'>NUA TRANS MEDIA Fresher Walk-in: Trainee - Developer On 5th to 7th June in Chennai<\/a><br><br><br>","<a href='http:\/\/freshersadda.com\/jsonFeed\/faJsonFeedDetails.php?jid=12026'>PCS Technology Recruits IT Helpdesk \/ Call Co Coordinator in Chennai<\/a><br><br><br>","<a href='http:\/\/freshersadda.com\/jsonFeed\/faJsonFeedDetails.php?jid=12025'>ICICI Bank Recruits Bank Jobs Chartered Accountants<\/a><br><br><br>","<a href='http:\/\/freshersadda.com\/jsonFeed\/faJsonFeedDetails.php?jid=12024'>BIOCON Recruits Engineering Jobs Executive\/ Jr Executive<\/a><br><br><br>","<a href='http:\/\/freshersadda.com\/jsonFeed\/faJsonFeedDetails.php?jid=12023'>INTEL Technology Recruits Engineering Jobs Research Intern<\/a><br><br><br>","<a href='http:\/\/freshersadda.com\/jsonFeed\/faJsonFeedDetails.php?jid=12022'>SUTHERLAND global Recruits Healthcare Jobs Medical Coder <\/a><br><br><br>"] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: Your error is right there. have you checked if its returning  a valid jSON?

Comment: can u share your code...

Comment: it is a JSONArray and not JSONObject. change it to JSONArray. try using Gson for parsing.

Comment: in your next response (when i clicked next url) is JSONArray of JSONArray which contain JSONObject. so its nested one so please parse accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value you are getting from the URL is a JSONArray not a JSONOBject. (Thats what the square brackets mean). Try this:

```
JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
JSONObject firstObject = json.getJSONObject(0);
JSONObject secondObject = json.getJSONObject(1);
...etc
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `JSONArray` is not a child of `JSONObject`.

`JSONArray` extends `java.lang.Object` only.

The signature of JSONArray class is:

```
public class org.json.JSONArray { 
     ... class body  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The clue is at the end of the exception: `... of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject`. The JSON at the given URL is valid JSON, but in the form of a `JSONArray`, not a `JSONObject`.

Try changing the line to `JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);` and it should work.